# How to confirm NS records are correct for delegating subdomain?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, sender-authentication-package

I've added the following NS records to my subdomain to delegate it to salesforce:

[image]

However, when I check the NS records on DNS Checker, it hasn't propagated. Should it be showing propagation (it's been about 72 hours)? Or will this not show anything until I've filled the SAP form and salesforce has done their thing.

I don't want to fill the SAP form before being sure that the DNS delegation is properly done. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duc Le is indeed correct in his answer, however people who are working with the DNS configuration of that particular domain, might not have the SAP form at hand. Here you can utilize the unofficial delegation checker: https://xnnd.com/dele.cgi

You don't have to wait until the form is filled out, as this is not a prerequisite for the delegation, as this is purely managed by the DNS records for the particular (sub)domain.

As you can see below, entering your SAP domain will provide a confirmation (if this delegation indeed is successful):

[image]

Comment: Yep that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to  fill the SAP form and submit, it will tell you whether it was propagated correctly or not, if it doesn't pass the validation then you won't successfully submit it.

[image]